# Serializer() method "constructor serializer() is not defined" in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, saxon

I have a problem in a class created for xslt transformation using SAXON. The serializer is imported and from this class a serializer is built.

```
Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
```

I receive the error message " the constructor serializer() is not defined".

when I CTRL+click on it, it says "source not found".

Note: the jar package of the Saxon HE library is added.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ORRz.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an API change between releases. In 9.5 the `Serializer` class had a public zero-argument constructor. This was deprecated in 9.6 and 9.7, and removed in Saxon 9.8.

The preferred alternative is to use the factory method:

```
processor.newSerializer()
```

The reason for the change was to ensure that the `Serializer` always has access to configuration information in the `Configuration` object.

It also allows us potential to introduce subclasses of `Serializer` in future releases, should we choose to do so.